# Not Allow user to take quiz twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am using Express, Passport, Handlebars and Mongoose/MongoDB to build a quiz for a website. I am trying to prevent the same user from taking the same quiz twice. There is only one quiz. Once they finish it, they cannot take it again. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
router.get('/tools/start-health-assessment', function(req, res) {
  User.find({
    _id: req.user._id,
    assessmentTaken: true
  }).then(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      res.redirect('/users/dashboard');
    }
  });
});
```

This route gets the instructions page that precedes the quiz. My logic is to use the Mongo query inside this route. If `assessmentTaken` is true, I want to ideally redirect the user back to the dashboard. The problem I am experiencing is a stalled webpage every time I try to get to the route above i.e. the loading bar never ends.

Comment: Why aren't you reading what comes back from mongodb? As in, `function(err, user) ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have req.user populated (I assume with the same model as in your db), why not just check that in the handler, rather than making another DB query?

EG:

```
router.get('/tools/start-health-assessment', function(req, res) {
    // assuming your Passport middleware won't let a request get here w/o a user on it. 
    if (req.user.assessmentTaken) {
      res.redirect('/users/dashboard');
    } else {
      res.render('health-assessment'); // or whatever you call it
    }
});
```